# Is it possible to provide authentication when our Identity Provider (ADFS) is unavailable?

Tags: single-sign-on

We have enabled SSO on our site, which is working as expected but sometime ago I found myself in a situation where my users are not able to access site since ADFS server is unavailable.

Is there a way through which we can redirect that request to login page if ADFS server is unavailable to authenticate it and provide automatic login??

Thanks in advance